# ActiveAdmin csv export records order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activeadmin

I have ActiveAdmin in my rails app. I was trying to disable default order which ActiveAdmin apply when retrieve records, I've add this to my resource:

```
 config.sort_order = ''
```

Now when I visit html version of page it properly get the records without order but when I export to csv it retrieves records with order:

```
SELECT  "vw_survey_packs".* FROM "vw_survey_packs" WHERE ("vw_survey_packs"."id" > 22542)  ORDER BY "vw_survey_packs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4209) on github. Basically: it's not possible without changing the code yourself.